# Extend an interface or aggregate interfaces

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm in a dilemma. I have an interface Parser and classes that implement it will parse concrete file formats. For example - CSVParser will parse CSV files, XMLParser will parse XML files and so on.

So, interface Parser would be:

```
public interface Parser{

    public SomeObject parseFile(String pathToFile);

}
```

On the other hand, some parsers will have additional parameter, for example, an array that will tell them which lines to skip in a file. Now this confuses me, should I extend Parser and add the method, something like:

```
public interface BetterParser extends Parser{
    public SomeObject parseFileConsideringParameter(String pathToFile, int[] whichLinesToSkip)
}
```

Or should I aggregate them so that my class needs to implement both:

```
public class concreteParser implements Parser, BetterParser{
}
```

I would like to have parser agnostic part in pipline, where you would say:

```
Parser parser = ParserFactory.giveMeParser(type);
SomeObject so = parser.parseFile(path);
```

The thing is, in some case I won't have the parameter that tells me which lines to skip.

I know I could create only a single method with both parameters, so some of the implementation would pass the other parameter and the other ones would pass null, but that just seems ugly.

I would really like to avoid bounding to concrete implementation, but how do I overcome this problem? Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Is line skipping format dependent? Is something specific to a specific parser, or is it something you need to do regardless of the format?

Comment: Thanks for the interest. Yes, it is format dependent. For some files it won't be needed, but for others will be.

Comment: Then it should be part of the concrete parser i.e not part of the interface. Make it an argument when you instantiate the parser or have the parser 'detect' that stuff somehow. At worst, you might have a 'service' injected in the parser which can be invoked like `svc.GetCSVLinesToSkip()`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for those interfaces is essentially so that service providers can bind an interface to its implementation. If said implementations have "variations", then one way to allow for such variations is to implement the regular `SomeObject parseFile(String pathToFile)` method, which calls `parseFileConsideringParameter()` with a default `whichLinesToSkip` argument to pass. Then, if you need to tell which lines to skip, you'd  check that the Parser is an `instanceof` BetterParser, then cast the Parser to BetterParser and use the method (but as explained below, `instanceof` is rarely the solution).

With that said, your question has two parts:

1. Aggregate or extend
2. How to deal with variations in implementations

For 1, it's really personal preference. Either will work, however extending may show that BetterParser *is* a Parser, rather than relying on the implementation to convey that, just by implementing both.

For 2, I sort of mentioned it above. However, most say that if you use `instanceof`, [there's probably a better way](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31). For that, you may consider having the service provider use two methods, one for getting a regular parser, and one for getting a SkippableParser (for example).

Answer (score 1):

> On the other hand, some parsers will have additional parameter, for example, an array that will tell them which lines to skip in a file. Now this confuses me, should I extend Parser and add the method, something like
>
> ```
>    public interface BetterParser extends Parser{
>         public SomeObject parseFileConsideringParameter(String pathToFile,     int[] whichLinesToSkip)
>     }
> ```

No, please, just don't.

You can try an approach using the [Decorator Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator).

```
interface Parser {
    public List<Token> parse(String pathToFile);
}

abstract class ParserDecorator implements Parser {
    protected Parser realParser;
    protected ParserDecorator(Parser rp) {}
    // delegates most of the methods to real parser...
}

class LineFilterParserDecorator extends ParserDecorator {
    private int[] linesToSkip;
    public LineFilterParserDecorator(Parser rp, int[] linesToSkip) {
        super(rp);
        this.linesToSkip = linesToSkip;
    }

    @override
    public List<Token> parse(Strint path) {
        List<Token> l = this.realParser.parse(path);
        // remove the skipped lines from the list
        return l;
    }
}

// Usage:

Parser myParser = new LineFilterParserDecorator(new CSVParser(...), new int{10, 20,30}); // will skip lines 10, 20 and 30
```